# How to extract read a zipped file?

Tags: java, zip

How can I extract a data from a zipped file uising JAVA libraries ? Is there a library that does unzipping and the I get the file and manipulate it ?

Comment: Deleted tag "information-extraction": it has **nothing** to do with compression (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_extraction).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the "java.util.zip" package.

See [this article by Sun (now Oracle)](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626093530/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/).

Comment: Other powerful options are TrueZip and 7-Zip-JBinding

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html
http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/JavaUncompress.shtml

```
import java.util.zip;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JavaUncompress{
public static void main(String args[]){
try{
  //To Uncompress GZip File Contents we need to open the gzip file.....
  if(args.length<=0){
    System.out.println("Please enter the valid file name");
  }
  else{
    String inFilename = args[0];
    System.out.println("Opening the gzip file.......................... :  opened");


    ZipInputStream zipInputStream = null;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new 

FileInputStream(inFilename));
    System.out.println("Opening the output file............ : opened");
    String outFilename = inFilename +".pdf";
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
    System.out.println("Transferring bytes from the 

compressed file to the output file........:
     Transfer successful");
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];  //size can be 

//changed according to programmer's need.
    int len;
    while ((len = zipInputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
      out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    System.out.println("The file and stream is ......closing.......... : closed"); 
    zipInputStream.close();
    out.close();
      }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
  System.out.println("Exception has been thrown" + e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The original question is asking about zip, not gzip.  The procedure for extracting zipfiles is different; see the article referenced in NomNom's answer.

Comment: The link to the package I referenced applies to zip and gzip, sorry about the example being gzip.

Comment: I'm somewhat amused that all your messages print "opened" "transferred" and "closed" in the same line as the "preparing to" message... when you actually haven't done any of it until later ^_^

Comment: @Steven Schlansker It was a quick copy and paste from here.  http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/JavaUncompress.shtml 
guess I should have checked it.

Answer (score 1):

Commons Compress
[http://commons.apache.org](http://commons.apache.org/compress/examples.html#zip)